# How do I join the Thieves' Guild in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I heard about the Thieve's Guild, and I want to know how to join it. I really need some extra cash since I'm always raiding places and bribing guards. I can't really fight them and get money from their corpses, since I suck at combat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> To join the Thieves Guild, travel to Riften and come into contact with
>   Brynjolf, who can be found at the market stalls or the Bee and Barb
>   tavern during the day. Brynjolf will approach you and question your
>   wealth, before inviting you to help him with a little plot. This
>   begins the first quest, A Chance Arrangement, in which you must steal
>   a ring and plant it on another person. If the quest is failed,
>   Brynjolf will still give you the next quest. Travel down to the canals
>   and enter The Ratway. Defeat the bandits and follow the tunnels to The
>   Ragged Flagon, headquarters of the Thieves Guild. Here, Brynjolf will
>   give you the next quest, Taking Care of Business, tasking you with
>   roughing up three business owners for debts he needs collected.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_%28faction%29)

Answer (score -6):

Someone will approach you in the bee and barb in Riften, he will then ask for your wealth before you can start the quest.

Comment: This is a repost of the accepted answer at best and misleading at worst.